# Pygame - How to check if object is currently moving

Tags: python, pygame

As the title says, How do I check to see if an object (in this case, a rect) is currently moving in pygame.

I've tried to create a variable of the previous position and see if the current position matches, but it just flickers between "True" and "False", which I'm assuming is because the object's location isn't changing faster than the game's update ticks

I'm currently changing the object's position by using:

```
def MoveButton(self,new_xpos,new_ypos):
    self.x_pos = new_xpos
    self.y_pos = new_ypos
```

Which is a function inside the object's class, and is being called constantly via key press.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple answers and was to solve that - The simplest of which is to add a `prev_x_pos` and `prev_y_pos` and say:

```
def MoveButton(self,new_xpos,new_ypos):
    self.prev_x_pos = self.x_pos
    self.prev_y_pos = self.y_pos
    self.x_pos = new_xpos
    self.y_pos = new_ypos
```

Then you could add a checkIfMoving function:

```
def checkIfMoving(self):
    self.isMoving = (self.prev_x_pos - self.x_pos != 0 or self.prev_y_pos - self.y_pos != 0)
```

Which would return True if the rect is moving. You can also just add the line of code, without the function, but i'd advise you put it inside an update functions that is run every frame.
Another, neater way, is to integrate physics by using vectors, which are the movement values. With vectors, you add their values to the pos_x and pos_y each frame, and in order to decide the actual movement of the player you  just change the value of the movement vector instead of just doing `self.pos_x -= speed`. These are also integrated in most game libraries, including PyGame. I advise you look them up, since improved physics usually result in the movement in the game feeling nicer for the player.
You could also just set in the mainloop `square.isMoving = False` and then immediately after it run the function, in which you write `square.isMoving = True` That way, whenever the code is being run and the square is in fact moving, it'll just set it to True. Make sure that if no moving buttons are being pressed, the function won't run.

Comment: The questioner had probably already tried that: *"[...] I've tried to create a variable of the previous position and see if the current position matches, [...]"*